# Performing a median split on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

I have a df with the following structure:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'varb': ['0.56', '0.74', '0.89', '0.99', '0.24', '0.76', '0.60'], 
               'response': ['141', '134', '72', '29', '34', '50', '128'],
               })
df
```

I want to perform a *median split* on 'varb' and have the top 50th percentile be put in group '2' and the bottom 50th percentile be put in group '1' so the resulting dataframe would look like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'varb': ['0.56', '0.74', '0.89', '0.99', '0.24', '0.76', '0.60'], 
               'response': ['141', '134', '72', '29', '34', '50', '128'],
               'median_split': ['2', '2', '2', '1', '1', '1', '2']})
df
```

How can I achieve this using python?

Comment: Why 0.99 is in 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you used response instead of varb for the median split in your example. You can use the [`quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.quantile.html) method of pandas DataFrame/Series. By default, it only computes the median, but you can use it to compute any percentile.

```
df["median_split"] = (df.response<df.response.quantile()).replace({True:1, False:2})
```